# Continue the loop if a Fatal Error is found in a Facebook publish stream script

Tags: php, facebook, loops, fatal-error, continue

I have the following PHP code:

```
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXX',
  'secret' => 'XXXX',
));
$ids = array('1234','5678','1348','1476');
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $USER_ID = $id; 
    $args = array( 
        'message'       =>  'Hello from XXXXX',
        'link'          =>  'http://www.xxxxx.com/',
        'caption'       =>  'Visit XXXXXXX.com for Facebook API Integration.',
        'picture'   =>  'http://www.xxxxxxx.com/busman.png'
    );
$post_id = $facebook->api("/$USER_ID/feed", "post", $args);
}
```

It works great, it happens that once in a while some users can uninstall or revoke access to the facebook application to publish on his/her behalf, and if that userid is in a loop the entire process stops there and the next users are not touched.

What can I do in order to continue the loop even when I get this fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action thrown in /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxxx/base_facebook.php on line 1254 <

BTW I am using the PHP SDK for Facebook. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try: try/cacth have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 0):

Try catching the exception.  Something like:

```
try {

    $post_id = $facebook->api("/$USER_ID/feed", "post", $args);

} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

    // Do something with the error if you want.
    // For example, remove it from your list so that your
    // script doesn't try to use this ID again.

} catch (Exception $e) {

    // Any other exception
}
```

More info on:

- Facebook API errors & exceptions (and codes):
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/
- Facebook API error handling with PHP:
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/
- Anatomy on a PHP exception:
  http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php
- Catching PHP Exceptions:
  http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php